# object.ParentNode generates error in UFT

Tags: firefox, vbscript, hp-uft

`Set parentObject = object.ParentNode` generates the error object is required with Firefox browser.

The result should be an object but it gives an array as a result.

Note:This code line works without any issues with IE browser.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers UFT supplies a bridge that allows the DOM to be used in VBScript

Comment: Please supply more information about the problem. I can't see the problem with UFT 12.54. How is `object` created? The following script correctly prints `DIV` for www.example.com  `Set obj = Browser("title:=.*").Page("title:=.*").WebElement("html tag:=h1").Object
Set parent = obj.parentNode
Print parent.tagName`

Comment: @Motti Ah, wasn't aware of that. Thanks for the information.